# Object Required Error for copy and paste between 2 workbooks

Tags: vba, object, copy, paste, required

```
    Sub CriticalSummerList()



Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = Workbooks("1")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")


Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("G:\")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set rng = [B1]
Set rng = Range(rng, Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

ws2.Select
rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited

    With Range("b1").CurrentRegion
        .Sort Key1:=.Range("b1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With
 
Set ws3 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet2")
 
ws3.Activate

Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row

With ws3
.Range("e2:l" & Lastrow).Copy
End With

wb1.Activate
ws1.Range("E3").Select

wb1.ws1.Paste ws1.[e3]



 
 

End Sub
```

I'm setting the range on wb2.ws2 to texttocolumn range B:B.
Copy from ws3 e2:L to last row and paste to wb1.ws1.
It is when i paste that i come across this error. I tried all other ways to paste the data however it keeps throwing object required error. Thank you for your help.
I'm setting the range on wb2.ws2 to texttocolumn range B:B.
Copy from ws3 e2:L to last row and paste to wb1.ws1.
It is when i paste that i come across this error. I tried all other ways to paste the data however it keeps throwing object required error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Change `wb1.ws1` to `ws1`.

Comment: `wb1.ws1` would throw an error "Object doesn't support this property or method", since the `Workbook` object model doesn't have a `ws1` member.  Are you sure `wb1` (and/or `ws1`) is/are actually set?  Is there some code you don't show?

Comment: Where is this code located, in `wb1`, in `wb2`, or in a third workbook? *"G:\"* is not a valid file path. Which is it? If `wb1` is **not** the workbook containing this code, what is its file extension, `.xlsx` or `.xlsm` or `.xlsb` or...?

Comment: I tried changing from wb1.ws1 to ws1 but it still throws "object..." error.

Comment: ws1 is the current sheet where it is copying and pasting TO and is in wb1. ws2 is the sheet where it is copying FROM and is in wb2. both wb1 and wb2 are xlsm.                                wb1 is what contains this code. I am running this macro from wb1 to copy form wb2 to wb1.

Comment: The "G.." address is valid. I just abbreviated it for the purposes of uploading here.